# fragment into other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, cardview

I'm working in an app. I have an activity where I have my menu, I select the options and instance a new fragment, it depends of the option of course. But now I have to create a image swiper inside the fragment (StudyFragment is named)...I don't know how.

I saw some tutorials about how to create it with card view but I don't understand how to use it in my app.

This is my menu.

Sorry for my bad English.

```
package co.intrasoft.quin_1;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case  R.id.action_category:
                        selectedFragment = CategoryFragment.newInstance();
                        break;
                    case  R.id.action_ranking:
                        selectedFragment = RankingFragment.newInstance();
                        break;
                    case  R.id.action_study:
                        selectedFragment = StudyFragment.newInstance();
                        break;
                    case  R.id.action_profile:
                        selectedFragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance();
                        break;
                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,selectedFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
        setDefaultFragment();
    }

    private void setDefaultFragment() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,CategoryFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

This is an example that I did.

- Main Activity

  package com.example.viviana.appfragment;

  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  ```
  private int[] images = new int []{
      R.drawable.cal1, R.drawable.cal2, R.drawable.cal3, R.drawable.cal4,
          R.drawable.cal5, R.drawable.cal6, R.drawable.cal7, R.drawable.cal8,
          R.drawable.cal9, R.drawable.cal10, R.drawable.cal11, R.drawable.cal12,
          R.drawable.cal13, R.drawable.cal14, R.drawable.cal15, R.drawable.cal16
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
      ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
      pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private class ImageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

      private ImageFragment imageFragment;


      public ImageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
          super(fm);
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment(images[position]);
          return fragment;
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return images.length;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

-xml of main activity

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

- Image Fragment class

  package com.example.viviana.appfragment;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

  /**

  - Created by viviana on 7/03/18.
    */

  public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {

  ```
  private int img;


  public ImageFragment() {
  }

  public ImageFragment(int img){
      this.img =img;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      ImageView imageView = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view,container,false);
      imageView.setImageResource(img);
      return imageView;
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: can you post code for what your fragment looks like and what youve tried?

Comment: I don't have code over this ... I made some tutorials, but apart of this project. I'm gonna upload it.